# Uploaded files changing permission and owner to root automatically

Tags: apache, file-upload, permissions, file-permissions, file-ownership

I´m having a weird issue, when trying to upload files directly from website. So I´ve set a gallery and other uploading folders as 755 with user permission, and all recursive directories and files as well, however every time I upload a file in question that becomes in 0 0 owner no matter what. I´ve checked and I am not able to figure out what can be wrong since I´ve set 755 and 777 permissions for everything. Templates are fine. My server is running in Apache Centos 6.5. What could I be missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `0 0 owner`? you mean no privileges at all? or owned by user/group 0/0? Apache by default runs as a non-privileged user, and cannot "give away" files to another user. Such a capability would allow any user to do a trivial denial-of-service on another by "gifting" enough data to use up the target's quota allowances.

Comment: What I meant was owner user/group 0 0 sorry